# redirect to home page and remove the back button on navigation bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

i have an simple ion sidebar app with links inside the sidebar so when the user taps on the link in the sidebar a  new view is loaded 
but when the user taps the back button i want them to go to the home page form the view in which they where.
i accomplish this using

```
 $state.go('state.name')
```

And it works fine but when i arrive at the home pace the sidebar "hamburger" icon is replaced with a back button to the view.

so is there a way to navigate to home without any history?
i am using all latest version of ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ionic `1.0.0-beta.14` you can do `$ionicHistory.clearHistory()`

More [info](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)